# Find conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> For two events A and B, the probability that A occurs is 0.6, the probability that B
> occurs is 0.5, and the probability that both occur is 0.3. Given that B occurred, what
> is the probability that A also occurred?

My work: $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{0.3}{0.5} = 0.6$ which matches the probability of A in the question? Did I do something wrong or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: You have calculated correctly, $\mathsf P(A\mid B)=0.6$.  Also... $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(B\mid A)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(A)}\\[1ex]&=\tfrac{0.3}{0.6}\\[1ex]&=0.5\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(B)\end{align}$$ But mostly, $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A)~\mathsf P(B)&=0.6\cdot 0.5\\[1ex]&=0.3\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(A\cap B)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct. To understand why it is that $P(A \mid B) = P(A)$ in this case, look up the definition of independent events at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Definition) and think about how that relates to your specific problem.